# filters for photo editing app

Tags: android, editing

i want to create photo editing app in android. But I don't know how to add filters to image. Will I have to create images for filters in photoshop or have to use java code for each filter? Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: what type of `filter` can u explain and what u have tried so far ?

Comment: simple filters like instagram

Comment: I have one horizontal bar in bottom in which all filters are placed. And above it, I have placed photo. Same like instagram. But I don't know what should I put in that filters so that if I click on that filters, image should get edited. Should I use images for that filters or it will be done by java code?